# How to create list from different length of lists using for loop in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, datetime, append

I have two lists, named **start** and **time**. **start** contains 3 datetime elements. **time** contains 3 lists, each having length of 841, 600, 840. start[0] contains a date of a particular year, I have to add every element of time[0] to generate another set of dates. This I have done successfully. But, now I want to loop over start and time. I have tried to do that using append function, but it gave me a list, size of 2281, which is basically the sum of total number of elements that time contains.

But I want a list, which will contain 3 different lists of size 841, 600, 840 respectively, with new sets of dates. Thank you.

For first element of start and first list of time (I am successful) :

```
all_dates = []
for i in range(len(time)):
    all_dates.append(start + dt.timedelta(days = time[i]))
```

Now for looping over start and time :

```
all_dates = []
for i in range(len(start)):
    for j in range(len(time[i])):
        all_dates.append(start[i] + dt.timedelta(days = time[i][j]))
```

Here I am expecting a list which will have 3 different lists, with each having same length just as time, that is 841, 600, 840 respectively (after the operation). Please let me know if you have any doubt. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new list inside the top for loop. Like this:

```
import datetime as dt

all_dates = []
for i in range(len(start)):
    current_dates = []  # create a new list for the current start value
    for j in range(len(time[i])):
        current_dates.append(start[i] + dt.timedelta(days = time[i][j]))
    all_dates.append(current_dates)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But can you explain why you have create a list inside loop, i checked whether it will work or not if I put it outside of the loop. Thank you

Comment: Sure. As Barmar pointed out you want to nest three lists (`current_dates[]`) inside a list (`all_dates[]`). These nested lists need to be defined inside the `for loop`. Otherwise all the dates get appended in the list defined outside the `for loop` and you get a list of length 841 + 600 + 840

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop needs to append to a nested list, which you then append to `all_dates`.

```
all_dates = []
for i in range(len(start)):
    l = []
    for j in range(len(time[i])):
        l.append(start[i] + dt.timedelta(days = time[i][j]))
    all_dates.append(l)
```

You can also do this with nested list comprehensions:

```
all_dates = [
    [start_time + dt.timedelta(days=t) for t in curtimes]
    for curtimes, start_time in zip(times, start)
]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But can you explain why you have create a list inside loop, i checked whether it will work or not if I put it outside of the loop. I want to understand the code. Thanks

Comment: If you don't create the list inside the loop, there will just be one list that you keep appending to. `all_dates.append(l)` doesn't make a copy of `l`.